# How to combine paths through a loop

Tags: c#, loops

I am creating a folder maze creator (creating one folder within another) application for some fun, but it seems to be much more complicated than what I first expected. I think examples will explain this better. Basically I want to do this

```
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName + i);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < iterations; ii++)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(dirName + i, dirName + ii));
        for (int iii = 0; iii < iterations; iii++)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(dirName + i, dirName + ii, dirName + iii));
            for (int iv = 0; iv < iterations; iv++)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(dirName + i, dirName + ii, dirName + iii, dirName + iv));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, instead of setting the number of nested loops, I wanted the user to be able to set that at runtime. So with some help from Programmers, I got this.

```
private void Recursion(int depth)
{
    if (depth >= depthMax)
        return;

    //string[] folderPlace = new string[depthMax + 1];
    //for (int ii = 0; ii < depthMax; ii++)
    //{
    //    if (ii <= depth)
    //    {
    //        folderPlace[ii] = dirName;
    //    }
    //   else
    //    {
    //        folderPlace[ii] = "";
    //    }
    //}

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        folderPlace[1] = dirName + i;
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName + i);
        Recursion(depth + 1);
    }

}
```

But I just can't seem to find a way to get the right path in an array so every folder goes where it should automatically...

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: you want to create a folder and put much more folder in this folder and so on?

Comment: @JensHorstmann Yeah, basically that, I'll update the question a bit

Comment: Are you sure about path.combine can accept more than 2 variables? And, yeah, I don't really get what is your purpose  about those codes since, IMHO, those codes has different logical meaning,

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan Overloads of Path.Combine can accept upto 4 parameters. Hand Of Cithuhlu there is a limit on the size of file path on windows system. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath . You might want to put some validation around user input.

Comment: @Sandeep : I just know that Path.Combine can accept upto 4 parameters. In msdn documentation, it just has 2 parameters (no overloading). Please read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx). And, no, it's not about **limit on the size of file path**. IMO, it's about creating directory in the _designated depth_ with _designated folders_.

Comment: @Heinz: The overload list has details of all the four overloads https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. The link that you shared is for the overload with two parameters.

Comment: Maybe because my .NetFramework stil not updated (still 3.5). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you have a look at this example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const string DirName = "Mydir";
    const string RootFolder = @"c:\test";

    public Form1()
    {

        CreateDirectories(0, 5, 5, RootFolder);


        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void CreateDirectories(int currentDepth, int maxDepth, int iterations, string root)
    {
        if (currentDepth > maxDepth)
        {
            return;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            var currentDirName = Path.Combine(root, DirName + i.ToString());
            Directory.CreateDirectory(currentDirName);
            CreateDirectories(currentDepth + 1, maxDepth, iterations, currentDirName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any special reason you included maxDepth, and iterations in the parameters of the CreateDirectiories function (apart from the fact that you can just change it where you called it)?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to know the difference between Iterations and Recursions.

Iterations are all types of loops (eg. `for`, `foreach`). Recursion means a method calls its self and provides some kind of an exit-condition to prevent endless exectution.

Recursions allow you to define the level of nesting for operations, but is considered slower. Iterations only allow you to define how many circles one iteration processes, but not the level of nesting which is kind of hard coded (the 3 nested loops in you first example). IMO Iterations are easier to understand and to develop, compared to recursion.

Your particular problem calls for a combined solution, where a method calls its self recursively inside iteration-circles.

A possible solution would look like below (the most interesting part is the `Magic(int, string)`-method, where i have added some comments to point out examples of the things I have explained above):

```
    private class FolderMaze
    {
        private const string SubDirectoryName = "Maze_";
        private readonly string baseDirectory;
        private readonly int depth;
        private readonly int nFoldersPerIteration;

        public FolderMaze(string baseDirectory, int depth, int nFoldersPerIteration)
        {
            this.baseDirectory = baseDirectory;
            this.depth = depth;
            this.nFoldersPerIteration = nFoldersPerIteration;
        }

        public void Magic()
        {
            this.Magic(0, this.baseDirectory);
        }

        private void Magic(int iteration, string iterationPath)
        {
            // exit condition
            if (iteration >= this.depth)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Iteration
            for (int i = 0; i < this.nFoldersPerIteration; i++)
            {
                var currentPath = Path.Combine(iterationPath, SubDirectoryName + i);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(currentPath);

                // recursive call to Magic(int string)
                this.Magic(++iteration, currentPath);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can call it like this:

```
var maze = new FolderMaze(Environment.CurrentDirectory, 2, 2);
maze.Magic();
```

I did put the solution inside a class, so that you can focus on the important things in the `Magic`-method, but you could also put this inside a single method w/o a surrounding class like in the answer provided by @Jean F.

Comment: +1 very well explained, but not accepted answer because I think @Jean F.'s answer answers the question more directly. Thanks anyway!